# "A great medal of people"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> George Stephanopoulos: Do you think he's misunderstood?
>
> Patrice Comey: Probably by some people. I think there's **a great medal of people** that, you know, see us all as Americans... ([source:YouTube](https://youtu.be/kVM1Sup-lNo?t=210))

I can't make sense of "a great medal (or metal/mettle) of people". It seems she is trying to say "a great number of people". What word is she reaching for if that utterance is mistaken? Or did I mishear?

Comment: I listened too, sounds like "middle" or "medal" like you said.  I can't think of a similar word that fits the context, but maybe in her mind she was searching for "deal" which shares all but one letter with "medal".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listening a bit further into the video, I think she said "middle".  She may have been searching for a different word, but based on what she said after, she could be referring to the group of people between left and right-leaning political viewpoints, collectively "the middle".

A few seconds later she said:

> "I think a lot of people in **the middle** that sit back....

Comment: That did cross my mind. I didn't consider it very likely because neither "a middle of people" or "a great middle of people" sounded particularly idiomatic to me. I'd be happy with "there's a sizeable middle that see us all as Americans". But now that you've explained it in relation to a later line, "a great middle of people" seems more likely now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! To be honest, the phrase didn't sound great when I scrutized it either.  Although I wouldn't have noticed that flaw if not pointed out.  I don't think it's idiomatic/natural, but I do think she said it :)